# Chef package version

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, monit, devops

I’m new with chef and I’m using this script https://github.com/apsoto/monit to install monit and configure it.
I’m trying to upgrade the version that is installed by default (5.6), I’m trying to do this in my recipe:

```
package "monit" do
  version "5.8"
  action :upgrade
end
```

but when I run the chef setup script, I receive a message that it’s up to date, Am I doing something wrong? it’s possible to upgrade it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can only install whatever packages your distro has available. I'm guessing you are on Ubuntu Trusty, which only ships 5.6. Stay tuned for a new cookbook at https://github.com/poise/poise-monit to fix these issues.